# optuna: Different Results Even With Same random_state

Tags: python, optuna

I am trying to understand why running the below code for hypterparameter tuning using optuna gives me different best parameter values even if I am running the exact same code with the same `random_state = 42`. Where is the random part coming from?

```
import optuna
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def objective(trial):
    digits = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
    x, y = digits.data, digits.target
    max_depth = trial.suggest_int("rf_max_depth", 2, 64, log=True)
    max_samples = trial.suggest_float("rf_max_samples", 0.2, 1)
   
    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(
        max_depth = max_depth,
        max_samples = max_samples,
        n_estimators = 50,
        random_state = 42
        )

    score = cross_val_score(rf_model, x, y, cv=3).mean()
    return score
study = optuna.create_study(direction = "maximize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials = 3)
trial = study.best_trial

print("Best Score: ", trial.value)
print("Best Params: ")
for key, value in trial.params.items():
    print("  {}: {}".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the inherent stochastic nature of the optimization algorithm that Optuna uses, not just the random behavior of the `RandomForestClassifier`.

Here's why you see different results even with the same `random_state` (for `RandomForestClassifier`!):

- **Random Search in Optuna**: Even though the `RandomForest` has a fixed `random_state`, the search algorithm used by Optuna itself is probabilistic. Optuna uses a combination of random search and Bayesian optimization. Each time you run the study, it can explore the hyperparameter space in a slightly different manner.
- **Sampling in Optuna**: The `trial.suggest_*` methods internally use samplers to suggest the next hyperparameters to try. The default sampler in Optuna is AFAIK `TPESampler`, which is based on Bayesian optimization and uses past trial results to suggest the next set of hyperparameters. This process has some randomness in it.

So to ensure reproducibility, you should set seeds for both Optuna and the algorithms or models you're tuning. In your case, you've set the random seed for `RandomForestClassifier`, but not for Optuna.

Try this to make your optimization reproducible:

```py
sampler = optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed=42)
study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize", sampler=sampler)
```

Comment: Even with that change I still get different results

Comment: @shsh check [this](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-optimization-results) yet, I will also think

Comment: I also noticed that if you add ```n_jobs = -1``` to ```study.optimize()``` then it will also give different results

Comment: @Iskander14yo, I am trying it with grid search in `optuna` and I am facing same situation. For each run using same `search space`, I am getting different best parameter values. Could you please help me on this. please let me know if you'd need a new question for this.